# MongoDB: out of memory

Tags: mongodb

I am wondering about the MongoDB memory consumption. I have read the corresponding manual sections and the other questions on the topic, but I think this situation is different. May I ask you for your advice?

This is the error from the DB log file:

```
Fri Oct 26 20:34:00 [conn1] ERROR: mmap private failed with out of memory. (64 bit build) 
Fri Oct 26 20:34:00 [conn1] Assertion: 13636:file /docdata/mongodb/data/xxx_letters.5 open/create failed in createPrivateMap (look in log for more information)
```

These are the data files:

```
total 4.0G
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb mongodb 4.0K 2012-10-26 20:21 journal
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb  64M 2012-10-25 19:34 xxx_letters.0
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 128M 2012-10-20 22:10 xxx_letters.1
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 256M 2012-10-24 09:10 xxx_letters.2
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 512M 2012-10-26 10:04 xxx_letters.3
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 1.0G 2012-10-26 19:56 xxx_letters.4
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb 2.0G 2012-10-03 11:32 xxx_letters.5
-rw------- 1 mongodb mongodb  16M 2012-10-26 19:56 xxx_letters.ns
```

This is the output of `free -tm`:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3836       3804         31          0         65       2722
-/+ buffers/cache:       1016       2819
Swap:         4094        513       3581
Total:        7930       4317       3612
```

Is it really necessary to have enough system memory so that the largest data files fit in? Why grow the files that much? (From the sequence shown above, I expect the next file to be 4GB.) I'll try to extend the RAM, but data will eventually grow even more. Or maybe this is not a memory problem at all?

I have got a 64 bit Linux system and use the 64 bit MongoDB 2.0.7-rc1. There is plenty of disk space, the CPU load is 0.0. This is `uname -a`:

```
Linux xxx 2.6.32.54-0.3-default #1 SMP 2012-01-27 17:38:56 +0100 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ulimit -a solved the mystery:

```
core file size (blocks, -c) 1
data seg size (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority (-e) 0
file size (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals (-i) 30619
max locked memory (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size (kbytes, -m) 3338968
open files (-n) 1024
pipe size (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority (-r) 0
stack size (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes (-u) 30619
virtual memory (kbytes, -v) 6496960
file locks (-x) unlimited
```

It worked after setting max memory size and virtual memory to unlimited and restarting everything. BTW, the next file had again 2GB.

Sorry for bothering you, but I was desperate. Maybe this helps somebody "googling" with a similar problem.

Comment: These were the commands to increase the limits: ulimit -v unlimited && ulimit -m unlimited