# I have an issue mongo db stops responding

Tags: linux, openvz

MongoDB service crashes and below is the error log:

```
ERROR: mmap private failed with out of memory. (64 bit build)
Assertion: 13636:file /var/lib/mongodb/_tmp_repairDatabase_4/dbname.0 open/create failed in createPrivateMap (look in log for more information)
```

and I could not start mongodb until I clear the data from mongodb data directory

Comment: Can you tell us when it crashes? Does it happen at a particular moment or after some action?

Comment: No particular moment it happens. It looks like every 3 days when data grows, mongo dies

Answer (score 0):

Which OS do you use ?

Did you look at:

[MongoDB: out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092705/mongodb-out-of-memory)

or

http://pranavl.wordpress.com/2012/09/12/mongodb-error-mmap-failed-with-out-of-memory-64-bit-build/

I am not expert in Mongo - but I run it without any problem..

Comment: It running in Linux Debian 6

Comment: OK - so.. Are you getting this error at the first time you start mongod? How much ram do you have on this machine ? how did you install ? apt-get install mongodb-org ?

Comment: MongoDB crashes and report says this error. Openvz Vm with 4 GB RAM. Yes, installed from repository.

Comment: try to start mongod with empty data directory

Comment: sudo mongod --dbpath /some/emptyfolder

Comment: Hey, we can start MongoDB with empty, no issue. But, I am trying to find why it is breaking. Please help.

Comment: I thing that the files with your db are broken.

Comment: you need to understand what is going on with you DB files

Comment: If you use some json or bson db file - try to import them one by one and you will find out which file are broken